# What is a .NET developer?

Tags: .net

I have been noticing that some software engineering jobs are asking for .NET developers, but I have never been given a definition (formal or informal) of what experience is required to be able to call yourself a .NET developer.

I have taken a couple classes where we needed to make Windows Forms every other week using Visual Studio, but I am pretty sure this is not sufficient.  I'm assuming you need to be familiar with most if not all technologies on the [.NET Framework Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx) , but I could be wrong, which is why I am asking.  :-)

So, what skills do you need to be able to market yourself as a .NET developer?  Or more specifically, what do employers expect you to know if you market yourself as a .NET developer?

Comment: Hey - I was just making a joke - take it easy guys. And btw this belongs in community wiki

Comment: @DroidIn: I don't see this as requiring CW. This isn't an esoteric "what does it mean for me to be a .NET developer" or "how can I be a .NET developer", it's a pragmatic "what is being referred to specifically" when someone lists ".NET developer".

Comment: This is discussion topic. There's way too many answers and none of these will be objective

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generally what's meant by that is a fairly intimate familiarity with one (or probably more) of the .NET languages (C#, VB.NET, etc.) and one (or less probably more) of the .NET stacks (WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, etc.).

As for a specific "formal definition", I don't think you'll find one beyond that. The job description should be specific about what they're looking for. I wouldn't consider a job listing that asks for a ".NET developer" and provides no more detail than that to be sufficiently descriptive.

Comment: also, one who codes primarily (but not necessarily exclusively) in .NET rather than other languages

Comment: +1 for the last part. Don't blindly go for the job if they don't even care to write their requirements.

Comment: @Jason: but to that point, .NET is not a language, it's a framework (more precisely a *set* of frameworks with a Common Language Runtime and a Base Class Library to tie them together)

Comment: @Jason it's hard to define which languages you should be coding to _not_ be considered .Net developer, given the proliferation of languages for .Net. :-)

Answer (score 22):

Though I consider myself a .NET developer, I don't prefer calling it that way. c# developer sounds much better and is a much clearer message: it says that I understand both C# and .NET (because C# and .NET are tied together). I could call myself a VB.NET developer, same story there.

What is a .NET developer? I don't know, because you cannot develop with .NET, if develop is a synonym for programming. .NET is the environment, the libraries, the languages, the CLR, the CLI, JIT, the LR, the BCL, the IDE and the IL. I find it a poor job description, but it may also mean that they don't really care: either you are an F#, a C#, an IronPython or a VB.NET developer, they're all implicitly and secretly .NET developers.

What do you need? A solid understanding why ".NET" is a poor job description and ask for a more precise one. Nobody can know *everything* of .NET, it is simply too wide. Orientate yourself to all sides of it and do both ASP.NET and WinForms. Don't forget Silverlight, WPF etc and two or three .NET languages.

In other words: know the forest by knowing what trees and flowers it habitats and specialize in knowing a few beautiful and common ones well.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the **minimum** would be to

- know one of the .Net Languages (C#, VB.NET, etc.)
- know the basic working of the .Net
  runtime
- know and understand the core parts of
  the .Net class libraries
- have an understanding about what
  additional classes and functions are
  available as part of the .Net class
  libraries

Answer (score 0):

CLR, BCL and C#/VB.Net, ADO.NET, WinForms and/or ASP.NET. Most of the places that require additional .Net technologies, like WPF or WCF will call it out explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Most .NET jobs I've run across also either explicitly or implicitly assume some knowledge of SQL-based RDBMSes. While it's not "part of the description", it's usually part of the job.